# Connecting the end of a set to the beginning

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

We have a set of nodes that are connected. Each node has a link to the next node in the chain. When the chain runs out, that end node just hangs out there. See the graphic below.

[Node path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkw62.png)

Each of these nodes has the same level, so as long as they are in the chain, they have the same number. So what I am hoping to do is come up with a cypher query that builds a link between the max ID and the MIN ID that share the same line number. So basically connecting  the end, with the beginning. Is there a clever way to do this ?

Comment: Do you want to do this in only one query or even 2 queries are fine?

Comment: 2 is fine ! I personally think 1 tends to be confusing but hey- I'll take all the help I can get.

Comment: Can you show your existing Cypher queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks some clarity, but what about thinking along the lines below ?

```
// find all levels in your dataset of nodes in the chains
MATCH (n)
WHERE (n)-[:NEXT]-()
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT n.level) AS levels
UNWIND levels AS level

// for each level, find the chain
MATCH (start {level:level})-[:NEXT*]->(end {level:level})
WHERE NOT (
            ({level:level})-[:NEXT]->(start) 
            OR 
            (end)-[:NEXT]->({level:level})
         )

// connect end to start 
MERGE (end)-[:MYRELTYPE]->(start)
```

Comment: Wow.. It may not have  been a clear question, but the answer was perfect. That did exactly what I needed and very quickly ! Thank you ! That might have taken me months. Thanks again